VSCode Jupyter Notebooks: How to Customize the Color of Cell Output (Text, Selected Text, Search Matched Text, e.g.)
I'm looking to modify the appearance of my Jupyter notebook in VSCode, specifically the color in the cell output (things in the red box). So far, I've tried adjusting settings like editor.findMatchBackground, editor.findMatchHighlightBackground, and editor.findMatchHighlightBorder, but these changes only affect the editor's color (things in the blue box), not that for output.
The only related setting I've found is notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor, which changes the background color of the output but does not address other colors. What I'm aiming for is to change the color similar to what editor.findMatchBackground does for the editor.


Settings.Json:
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"editor.foreground": "#ffffff"}


Thanks you! This do changes the color of text in output cell.
Do you have any idea about how to change the color of the background of selected or search matched text?

@StupidBoy If the Jupyter notebook uses the theme editor foreground and background colors it most likely uses the select and search theme colors too. Get there theme names and change them in workbench.colorCustomizations, best to do it by theme name

@rioV8 Thank you for the advice! However, it appears that the specific setting I want to configure isn’t available. I haven't found any themes that change the background color for Selected Text and Search Matched Text in output cell.

then use the Developer Tools to inspect which style is applied to the text, maybe it is a Decorator and they are found in a different div, sibling of the div with the syntax highlighting
